# Curl to Python using the Request library

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to translate Curl to Python, but I'm getting something wrong. Please help.

CURL:

```
body=$(cat << EOF
{
  "order": {
    "units": "-100",
    "instrument": "EUR_USD",
    "timeInForce": "FOK",
    "type": "MARKET",
    "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
  }
}
EOF
)

curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <AUTHENTICATION TOKEN>" \
  -d "$body" \
  "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<ACCOUNT>/orders"
```

PYTHON:

```
import requests
import json

def market_buy():
    header = {"Accept": "application/json",
               "Authorization": "Bearer <my auth code>"
             }
    data = {
    "order": {
        "units": "100",
        "instrument": "EUR_USD",
        "timeInForce": "FOK",
        "type": "MARKET",
        "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
      }
    }
    url = "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<myaccount>/orders"
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)    
    print(r.text)
market_buy()
```

Error Message:

```
{"errorMessage":"Insufficient authorization to perform request."}
```

I've double-checked my credentials. I'm thinking something is wrong with the code.

Comment: In your curl example you set `Content-type`, but in python you've got `Accept` instead. It shouldn't affect authorization, but could you make those two match just to check?

Answer (score 0):

A direct translation from cURL to Python requests would be this:

```
from requests import post

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer <AUTHENTICATION TOKEN>",
}

data = {
    "order": {
        "units": "100",
        "instrument": "EUR_USD",
        "timeInForce": "FOK",
        "type": "MARKET",
        "positionFill": "DEFAULT",
    }
}

post(
    "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<myaccount>/orders",
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
)
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess you are missing the `SSL cert verification` and `basic authentication`.

You can turn off SSL cert verification with the verify flag, and use basic authentication by specifying auth.

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests
import json

def market_buy():
    header = {"Accept": "application/json",
               "Authorization": "Bearer <my auth code>"
             }
    data = {
    "order": {
        "units": "100",
        "instrument": "EUR_USD",
        "timeInForce": "FOK",
        "type": "MARKET",
        "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
      }
    }
    url = "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<myaccount>/orders"
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'admin'), verify=False)    
    print(r.text)
market_buy()
```

I guess the above should work.

Comment: Why do you think auth is needed? The authorization header is already included. Also the error proves that a response was received which means it's not the SSL verification issue (which you *REALLY* shouldn't disable when dealing with financial APIs)

Comment: If you see this error `"Insufficient authorization to perform request."` it is related to authorization, so either its related to SSL issue or either the site is blocking you while you are trying to send/receive a request.

Comment: `verify=False` prevents the client from verifying the server certificate. If the verification failed, you wouldn't receive any kind of JSON response - it would be a connection failure on requests/urllib3 level before any data is received.

Comment: I guess, just speculating might be the access token has expired for the API.